# error[E0554]: `#![feature]` may not be used on the stable release channel

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I am having the following error with the `math` module in my Rust program.

How can I resolve it?

```
error[E0554]: `#![feature]` may not be used on the stable release channel
 --> C:\Users\pc\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\math-0.10.0\src\lib.rs:3:12
  |
3 | #![feature(drain_filter)]
  |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^

error[E0554]: `#![feature]` may not be used on the stable release channel
 --> C:\Users\pc\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\math-0.10.0\src\lib.rs:4:12
  |
4 | #![feature(bool_to_option)]
  |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

   Compiling rand_distr v0.4.3
For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0554`.
error: could not compile `math` due to 2 previous errors
warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
```

Comment: You're using some library that expects nightly Rust with stable Rust, that is all we can tell.

Answer (score 1):

The error message says that some module is using an unstable feature (two, actually). For example, `drain_filter` is unstable while [issue 43244](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/43244) is open.

Besides knowing whether or not you wrote "`#[feature(...` yourself, you can see that the file with the error starts with `.cargo\registry\` so it's in a crate that you're using.

The reason for the error is that an unstable feature may change quite a bit. If you use this code and expect it to "just work" it may fail in extremely surprising ways for your users. So the assumption is that you are using the "stable" channel of Rust and don't want unstable features suddenly breaking things.

If you *do* want unstable features breaking things, you can switch to the "nightly" channel:

```
rustup update -- nightly
```

This will allow you to use `#[feature]` either in your own modules or in unstable crates.

Comment: yeah, and how to resolve this?

Comment: Update the math crate: Check if there is a newer version of the math crate that does not rely on unstable features. You can do this by checking the crates.io website or by running cargo update in your project directory.

Comment: Didn't solve the issue.

Comment: `rustup update -- nightly`

Comment: still get the same error after rustup update -- nightly, i had to do rustup default nightly as well